# Custom views are not showing up properly

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I am trying to show 3 custom views in an iOS screen but only one of them is showing up. 2nd one started showing up a bit in improper way after putting alot of `constraints` and third one is completely not showing up.For test I am calling the same view three times. See the code. I have just started doing iOs so just forgive me if I am making any blunder or obvious mistake.

I have tried to put constraints accordingly, put a scrollview behind but none of this seems to be working

[image: I am getting this result]
[image: Here is storyboard screenshot and constraints]

I have remover container3 from `storyboard` because when I add it, the container2 doesn't show-up even slightly. Please help me with this layout problem.

```
class TestCustomViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var container : UIView?

@IBOutlet weak var container2 : UIView?

@IBOutlet weak var container3 : UIView?

var testView: CustomView!
var testView2: CustomView!
var testView3: CustomView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ////////First View//////
   testView = createGearItemView()
    testView.frame = (container?.frame)!
    container?.addSubview(testView)
    /////////Second View//////
    testView2 = createGearItemView()
    testView2.frame = (container2?.frame)!
    container2?.addSubview(testView2)
    ////// THird View/////////
    testView3 = createGearItemView()
    testView3.frame = (container3?.frame)!
    container3?.addSubview(testView3)
}

func createGearItemView () -> CustomView {
    let view = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView)!

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return view
}

}
```

Comment: You should definitely take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except of the fact that you should familiarize yourself with Auto Layout (see [Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)) you have to use the containers' `bounds` as `frame`s for your subviews (although it might not be the correct ones yet in `viewDidLoad`):

```
testView.frame = (container?.bounds)!
...
```

An even better way is using Auto Layout for your subviews instead of setting the `frame`s directly:

```
testView = createGearItemView()
container?.addSubview(testView)
testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container!.topAnchor).isActive = true
testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container!.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container!.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
testView2...
```